# YouTube Video Feed Thumbnails (without black bars)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube-api, thumbnails

I have managed using the YouTube API to fetch thumbnails for my list of videos, however they have black bars top and bottom of the UIImage I get. How can I fetch a thumbnail without these bars and even better a higher quality thumbnail?

Here is the code I use currently:

```
GDataEntryBase *entry = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *thumbnails = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup] mediaThumbnails];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[thumbnails objectAtIndex:0] URLString]]];
        UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also worth noting that all thumbnails are currently in a 4:3 aspect ratio, for historical purposes. If the underlying video is 16:9 and you plan on using a 16:9 player, then it makes sense to position the thumbnail so that the top and bottom black bars are hidden. That's independent of whether you use a lower-resolution or higher-resolution thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

Well this answer gave me the hint, so I went ahead and took a guess.

[How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)

Turns out if I just change the index from 0, to 1 of my data object I get a higher quality thumbnail. Magic, easy.